# How to change complex LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

PercentRelativeLayout is deprecated as of API 26 and I created this layout prior to the deprecation. Does anyone know what would be the best way to change this complex layout to a ConstraintLayout whilst making sure the design stays exactly the same?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map_stationmap_darktheme"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewSun"
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sun_white" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/switch_tgl"
            app:layout_widthPercent="20%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageViewSun">
            <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/switch_stationmap_darktheme"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewMoon"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_moon_white"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/switch_tgl"/>
    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on the conversion of the `PercentRelativeLayout` to `ConstraintLayout`, there are a couple of approaches. If you are the recent beta release of `ConstraintLayout` you can use a couple of new attributes that seemed geared to help the sunsetting of the percent layouts:

```
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
```

There is not a lot of documentation online for this feature. [Here](https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/whats-new-in-constraint-layout-1-1-x-f0bdd4dbdfb3) is one that I ran across.

If you are not on the beta release, you can still accomplish what you want by using guidelines and constraining your views between those guidelines. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45677238/6287910) is an answer to a question that you may find useful on how to use both of these techniques.