# How to create this layout using ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have a problem with made this screen xml: [image: problem]

Maximum height of RelativeLayout must be 50% of all screen height.
And if height of body layout is more than 50%, relative layout height must decrease. I can't understand how to set relative layout max_height to 50%. Thanks.
Xml code of screen:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guide_line">

        <LogoView
            android:id="@+id/logo_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:lv_textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guide_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guide_line" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update**: i added guideline, but if my framelayout height will be more than 50%, relativeLayout height must decrease, but it isn't : content of framelayout goes offscreen

Comment: use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="50"`

Comment: you can use `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"` to both of your layout in constraint layout.

Comment: @JeelVankhede, but if my body layout will be less than 50%, height of logo layout will expand

Comment: Okay, then use the guideline solution provided by @Atif, it'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fl_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LogoView
            android:id="@+id/logo_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:lv_textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int mainHeight = dm.heightPixels;
    Log.i(TAG, "mainHeight: " + mainHeight);

    FrameLayout flLayout = findViewById(R.id.fl_container);
    flLayout.setMinimumHeight(mainHeight / 2); // <-- Set pixel value, not dp!
}
```

I think it is not half of height perfectly, but this way will be solution that you want.

Answer (score 1):

use  [Guide Line](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline)

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/centerMargin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".50"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: i tried this component, but cant understand how to accept this for my problem, because guideline works like padding (if i understand)

Comment: simply add this guideline in your xml and see in design you will see 50% layout separator just add your view like start to bottom of centerMargin

Answer (score 0):

Add `Guideline` with orientation that you want. Then, add constraint each views with that line.

You can set up the fixed size `Guideline` with this attributes - `app:layout_constraintGuide_begin` or `app:layout_constraintGuide_end`.

Also, if you are thinking about using `ConstraintLayout`, then `match_constraint(= 0dp)` is better than `match_parent`. In this case, constraints with parent must be set together.

This is the completed xml code that used `Guideline`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LogoView
            android:id="@+id/logo_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="144dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_horizontal" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i wrote the same code, but if my framelayout height will be more than 50%, relativeLayout height must decrease, but it isn't : content of framelayout goes offscreen :/

Comment: Are you meaning that `RelativeLayout` will be flexible with height of 
 `FrameLayout`, right?

Comment: yes, but only if framelayout height more that half height of screen, if it's not, framelayout and relative must be the same height (50 - 50)

Comment: Then, you don't need to Guideline. Just set constraint `relativeLayout` 's bottom to Top of `fl_container`. And you must set `minHeight` of `fl_container` with half of device's screen programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Some new properties came under Constraint layout 1.1.0 onwards.

To Set layout height at 50% of the screen, You may do like this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
```

Here .5 is considered as 50% height of screen.

refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45652413/6151137